# How to exclude a specific tag from the list of tags for the current post?

Tags: tags, exclude

I would like show a list of tags assigned to the current post, but exclude one by tag id.

I tried excluding it from the array of objects returned from `wp_get_post_tags`, something like this:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID, array(
       'exclude' => 13
    )
);
```

But it doesn't looks like the `wp_get_post_tags` function supports exclude.

Am I wrong, or is there a better function to use in this case?

Comment: when you output the tags, check each one and don't output it if it's the tag you want to exclude. there is no function that has an exclude parameter for fetching terms assigned to an object.

Answer (score 1):

### METHOD 1 - `wp_get_post_terms()`

We can make use of the `wpse_exclude` parameter to exclude and array of terms from the list of post terms. [`wp_get_post_tags()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_tags/) internally uses [`wp_get_post_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_terms/) which uses [`wp_get_object_terms()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_object_terms/). When looking at the source of the latter, we see that we can make use of the [`wp_get_object_terms` filter](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_get_object_terms/) to filter the output from the function.

With this in mind, we can run the following filter on the output when we pass an array of id's to `wpse_exclude`: (***NOTE:*** Untested and requires PHP 5.4+)

```
add_filter( 'wp_get_object_terms', function ( $terms, $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args )
{
    // Lets first make sure that we have terms, and only target the post_tag taxonomy
    if (    !$terms
         || is_wp_error( $terms )
    ) 
        return $terms;

    if ( 'post_tag' !== $taxonomies )
        return $terms;

    // Now we can check if our custom argument is passed and valid
    if ( !isset( $args['wpse_exclude'] ) )
        return $terms;

    // Make sure that filds are not set to names
    if ( 'names' === $args['fields'] )
        return $terms;

    // Lets validate sanitize the array of integers, might be bit verbose though
    $excluded_id_array = filter_var(  
        $args['wpse_exclude'], 
        FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        [
            'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
            'options' => ['min_range' => 1]
        ]
    );

    if ( !$excluded_id_array )
        return $terms;

    // Everything checks out, lets exclude the terms
    $new_array = [];
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( in_array( $term->term_id, $excluded_id_array ) )
            continue; // Skip the excluded term

        $new_array[] = $term;
    }

    // We can now return out terms
    return $new_array;
}, 11, 4 );
```

**USAGE**

```
$args = [
    'wpse_exclude' => [1,2,4] // Array of tag ids to eclude
];
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( get_the_ID(), $args );
```

### IMPORTANT NOTE ON ABOVE METHOD

The method above is quite verbose. `wp_get_object_terms()` (*which is used internally by `wp_get_post_tags()`*) will result in an extra db call per post. Depending on the amount of posts being returned, this method can end updoing quite a number of unnecessary db calls. It is up to you to except this extra db call per post depending on what you need to do

### METHOD 2

A faster and less intrusive method would be to write a simple wrapper function for `get_the_tags()`. `get_the_tags()` uses `get_the_terms()` which uses all term info from the term cache. By default, any query will cache all post terms for the posts queried, so any function that uses `get_the_terms()` will not do any extra db call to get post term info.

IMHO, I would prefer this method above the other method as it is less verbose

```
function wpse_230208_get_the_tags( $post_id = 0, $exclude = [] )
{
    $post_id = filter_var( $post_id, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
    if ( !$post_id )
        return false;

    // Get the post tags
    $tags = get_the_tags( $post_id );

    // If there are no tags, lets bail early
    if ( !$tags )
        return false;

    // Check if we have a value for $exclude, if not, return get_the_tags
    if ( !$exclude )
        return $tags;

    // Validate the array of excluded ids
    $excluded_id_array = filter_var(  
        $exclude, 
        FILTER_VALIDATE_INT,
        [
            'flags'   => FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY,
            'options' => ['min_range' => 1]
        ]
    );

    if ( !$excluded_id_array )
        return $tags;

    // Lets exclude the tags
    $new_tag_array = [];
    foreach ( $tags as $tag ) {
        if ( in_array( $tag->term_id, $excluded_id_array ) )
           continue; // Skip the excluded tag

        $new_tag_array[] = $tag;
    }

    return $new_tag_array
}
```

**USAGE**

```
$tags = wpse_230208_get_the_tags( get_the_ID(), [1,2,4] ); // Note the array of id's to be excluded as 2nd args
```

Comment: I like how you validated the input via `filter_var` with  options. ps: I vaguely remembered the [`wp_is_numeric_array()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_is_numeric_array/) function, so I checked it out again but it's not suitable since it's only meant for the array keys and returns true if `is_string()` is false for all keys ;-)

Comment: @birgire I tend to like the PHP filters ;-)

Answer (score 1):

*Here's an approach similar to what @Milo suggests.*

Let's say we have:

```
$tags = wp_get_post_tags( 123 );
```

If we need to filter out the term with `term_id` `15`, we can use [`wp_list_filter`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_filter):

```
$_tags = wp_list_filter( $tags, [ 'term_id' => 15 ], 'NOT' );
```

where the `NOT` is the operator for excluding it.

If we also need to pluck out a single attribute we can use [`wp_filter_object_list`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_filter_object_list):

```
$_tags = wp_filter_object_list( $tags, [ term_id => 15 ], 'NOT', 'slug' );
```

where we pluck out e.g. the `slug` attribute.

*You should also check out the informative answer by @PieterGoosen, e.g.  about the flexible custom `wpse_exclude` attribute and the extra db call in `wp_get_post_tags()`.*

Comment: Jip, learned something new here. Will dig into that function a bit ;-)